# Bluetooth Profile Switch on Ubuntu

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, pavucontrol, a2dp

I was wondering if anyone know a good way to switch a Bluetooth headset profile directly from the desktop tray ?

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and the profiles to switch between are HSP/HFP and A2DP. As of right now, the only method I know of is to open `pavucontrol` and to manually change the profile there. Yet, I'm looking to do it more easily using desktop tray.

Comment: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/906/sound-output-device-chooser/ should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This perl script does an attempt at doing just that:

https://github.com/jikamens/bt_pa_auto_switcher

For a manual switcher, there is also a Gnome Shell extension that can  be useful:

https://github.com/kgshank/gse-sound-output-device-chooser